# Emacs term loses characters when using ps and grep

Tags: term, grep

I'm trying to use different terminals on Emacs.
The one I'm currently trying is `term`.

When I execute a `ps` command and `grep` its output on Emacs, I don't get the same result as in `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, etc...

This is what I get on Emacs:

```
etomort@elx306b6vv:~$ ps -ef | grep juniper
etomort  28860 28781  0 11:41 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto juniper
etomort@elx306b6vv:~$ ps -ef | grep 13109
etomort  13109     1  0 09:51 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/home/etomo
etomort  28876 28781  0 11:41 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 13109
```

Bear in mind that *greping* by process id does not either include juniper on its output.

And this is what I get on `gnome-terminal`:

```
etomort@elx306b6vv:~$ ps -ef | grep juniper
etomort  13109     1  0 09:51 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/home/etomort/.juniper_networks/tncc.jar net.juniper.tnc.NARPlatform.linux.LinuxHttpNAR log_level 2 postRetries 6 ivehost www.myvpn.org Parameter0 interval=0;process_timeout=5;failurl=;cert_md5=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j;hash_key=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j;id=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h9i0j;logging=0 locale en home_dir /home/etomort user_agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
etomort  28775 22252  0 11:40 pts/11   00:00:00 grep --color=auto juniper
```

So it seems that **Emacs term** loses characters somewhere between the `ps` and the pipe before the `grep`.

*Note:* I'll check in *Meta Stack Exchange* how to present better the output of `ps`, since I would prefer them truncated.

Comment: What does `ps -ef` show in emacs before you pipe it to grep? I think the ps output is truncated from the Emacs shell. Maybe `ps -ef -w -w` to force unlimited output width will help?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Emacs shell is telling `ps` what the column width is, and that causes `ps` to truncate its output. You can explicitly set the output width to unlimited by setting the `-w` argument twice: `ps -ef -w -w`. This overrides whatever settings Emacs is setting in shell mode.

Answer (score 2):

As correctly guessed by [Tyler](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17180), what's happening is that `ps` is truncating the output to the width of the terminal when it's running in Emacs Term, but not when it's running elsewhere. You can see that in the line where you grep for `13109`. Note that it's `ps` doing the truncation, not the terminal.

The reason this happens is that Term sets the `COLUMNS` environment variable to the window width. Most other terminals do not do this. Your shell probably sets the `COLUMNS` variable, but as an shell variable only, not as an environment variable (i.e. it isn't exported). Compare:

```
echo $COLUMNS
env | grep COLUMNS
```

in Term and in other terminals.

The `ps` command uses the `COLUMNS` variable to determine the width of its output, even when its output isn't going to the terminal. On Linux and *BSD (including OSX), you can pass the `w` option twice to tell `ps` not to truncate lines. If `COLUMNS` is not in the environment, most `ps` implementations (including Linux) don't truncate the output if it isn't going to the terminal.

```
ps -efww | grep juniper
```

or

```
unset COLUMNS
ps -ef | grep juniper
```

or alternatively

```
ps $(pgrep -f juniper)
```